# How to represent e^z in android studio as a text?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not able to represent `e^(z)` in android studio.
Also to represent `z^(2)`.

How can I use these as a text inside text view? 
Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the text by code as a HTML string

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(txtString));
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("e<sup>z</sup>"));
```